# map is not a function when reading data from json file in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am learning ReactJs So I am trying to read a data from json file in ReactJs.I was going through the turorial and tried this but i am getting an error message "map is not a function" in the browser.

my App.js file looks like this:

```
mport React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import Data from "./data.json";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

function App() {
  render();
  return Data.User.map((post) => {
    <div>
      <h1>{post.uid}</h1>
      <p>{post.Name}</p>
    </div>;
  });
}

export default App;



    data.json file:

        {
          "User": [
            {
              "uid": "ab123",
              "Name": "abc",
              "Lastname": "def",
              "Email": "abc@gmail.com",
              "Groups": [
                {
                  "EVERYONE": "TestGroup1"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
```

Comment: your data should be an array, I guess it's an object in your case, show your data.json file...

Comment: {
  "User": [
    {
      "uid": "ab123",
      "Name": "abc",
      "Lastname": "def",
      "Email": "abc@gmail.com",
      "Groups": [
        {
          "EVERYONE": "TestGroup1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the User property, map function is only valid on Arrays

```
return data.User.map((post) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{post.uid}</h1>
        <p>{post.Name}</p>
      </div>
    );
  });
```

Comment: Now i am getting thsi error: ×
Error: App(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

Comment: @Sarabjeet check the ocode aagain you need a return in front

Answer (score 1):

im not sure what  you r doing but i see you are returning something out of render function(i assume App is a component not a function)

```
export class App extends React.Component {
  render(
      return Data.User.map((post) => {
        <div>
        <h1>{post.uid}</h1>
        <p>{post.Name}</p>
        </div>;
      });
  );
}
```